# My sprites does connect, but in the middle you can still ''fall through''

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I got 2 sprites and a ball. I started a sprite at the point 0,400 and one on 250,400. Both sprites are the same and they are 250 long and 10high (in my WorkshopContent). I use a ball to bounce on the sprites which works. But when the ball is in the middle of the sprites (around 250,400) the ball falls through. I have no idea why.

My ball is 29,30.

```
protected override void Initialize()
        {
            ball1 = new StuiterBall();
            ball1.texture = "voetbal";
            ball1.Position = new Vector2(0, 150);
            allSprites.Add(ball1);

            Obstakel obstakel1 = new Obstakel();         
            obstakel1.Position = new Vector2(0, 400);
            obstakel1.texture = "witterechthoek";
            allSprites.Add(obstakel1);
            allSpriteObstakels1.Add(obstakel1);

            Obstakel obstakel3 = new Obstakel();
            obstakel3.Position = new Vector2(250, 400);
            obstakel3.texture = "witterechthoek";
            allSprites.Add(obstakel3);
            allSpriteObstakels1.Add(obstakel3);
        }


private void checkCollisions()
        {
            Rectangle rectball1 = new Rectangle((int)ball1.Position.X, (int) ball1.Position.Y, 30, 29);

            foreach (ISprite s in allSpriteObstakels1) {
                Rectangle rectSprite = new Rectangle((int)s.Position.X, (int)s.Position.Y, 250, 10);
                Rectangle overlap = Rectangle.Intersect(rectball1, rectSprite);
                if (!overlap.IsEmpty)
                {
                    s.CollisionWith(ball1);
                    ball1.CollisionWith(s);      
                }

            }

        }
```

Stuiterball.cs, collisionwith method:

```
public void CollisionWith(ISprite s)
        {      
                Speed.Y = -Speed.Y;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to use is [Rectangle.Intersects()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464123.aspx):

```
bool isCollision = rectball1.Intersects(rectSprite);
if (isCollision)
{
    s.CollisionWith(ball1);
    ball1.ColisionWith(s);
}
```

Comment: Doens't work :/ This has exactly the same problem with my old code. The collision is there, but at the end of the first sprite, the ball doens't have a collision anymore and just falls through the ractangle

Comment: Could it be that your ball isn't falling through at all? Maybe your `CollisionWith()` method is making it bounce twice? Once up and then down again? Making it look like it's falling through. I'd have to see your `CollisionWith()` method.

Comment: I added this method in my question above. And I understand when you mean, but this isn't the problem. This happens sometimes, and it will go slow through it. But when the ball comes in the middle of the 2blocks, it just falls through it with the same speed. Maybe because it has a collision with both of the blocks at the same time?

Comment: I will just make the position of ball 1,29. I don't see another solution

Comment: You could add a `break` statement if there's a collision. That way it would only collide with one obstacle or the other, but not both.